# Persistence Context v. Transaction

Tags: hibernate

While reading [Hibernate in Action](http://www.manning.com/bauer/), it comments on the following code:

```
public CreateEditItemService() throws Exception { 
    em = JPA.createEntityManager();
}
```

> No transaction is started at this time, only a persistence context is opened.

What's the difference between a `persistence context` and a `transaction`?

Answer (score 0):

the persistence context is https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/managed
while the transaction is a database feature